# DataTable - Custom Breakpoints for Responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, semantic-ui

I'm creating a DataTable ( Semantic UI) where I need a custom breakpoints for my table. I'm trying to change the break value at js code

```
"breakpoints: [{ name: 'fablet',  width: 768 }]"
```

to

```
breakpoints: [{ name: 'fablet',  width: 650 }]
```

I had made the changes in my JS code but It's not working. I don't know what I did wrong.

I had [checked](https://datatables.net/reference/option/responsive.breakpoints) the DataTable JS documentation for responsive table breakpoints.

Here is my code:

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
    responsive: {
        breakpoints: [
            { name: 'fablet',  width: 650 }
        ]
    }
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.semanticui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.semanticui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="ui celled table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>S.No.</th>
   <th>Author Name</th>   
   <th>Post Title</th>
   <th>Published Date</th>
   <th>Manage Ads</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>01</td>
   <td>Tiger Nixon</td>   
   <td>UI Developer</td>
   <td>2011/04/25</td>
   <td>
    <div class="ui buttons">
     <button class="ui green button">Edit</button>
     <div class="or"></div>
     <button class="ui orange button">Delete</button>
    </div>   
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>02</td> 
   <td>Garrett Winters</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>     
   <td>2011/07/25</td>
   <td>
    <div class="ui buttons">
     <button class="ui green button">Edit</button>
     <div class="or"></div>
     <button class="ui orange button">Delete</button>
    </div>   
   </td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>03</td>   
   <td>Ashton Cox</td>
   <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
   <td>2009/01/12</td>
   <td>
    <div class="ui buttons">
     <button class="ui green button">Edit</button>
     <div class="or"></div>
     <button class="ui orange button">Delete</button>
    </div>   
   </td>     
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>04</td>   
   <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
   <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
   <td>2012/03/29</td>
   <td>
    <div class="ui buttons">
     <button class="ui green button">Edit</button>
     <div class="or"></div>
     <button class="ui orange button">Delete</button>
    </div>   
   </td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>05</td>   
   <td>Airi Satou</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>2008/11/28</td>
   <td>
    <div class="ui buttons">
     <button class="ui green button">Edit</button>
     <div class="or"></div>
     <button class="ui orange button">Delete</button>
    </div>   
   </td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>06</td>   
   <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
   <td>Integration Specialist</td>
   <td>2012/12/02</td>
   <td>
    <div class="ui buttons">
     <button class="ui green button">Edit</button>
     <div class="or"></div>
     <button class="ui orange button">Delete</button>
    </div>   
   </td>     
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>07</td>   
   <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
   <td>Sales Assistant</td>
   <td>2012/08/06</td>
   <td>
    <div class="ui buttons">
     <button class="ui green button">Edit</button>
     <div class="or"></div>
     <button class="ui orange button">Delete</button>
    </div>   
   </td>     
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>08</td>   
   <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
   <td>Integration Specialist</td>
   <td>2010/10/14</td>
   <td>
    <div class="ui buttons">
     <button class="ui green button">Edit</button>
     <div class="or"></div>
     <button class="ui orange button">Delete</button>
    </div>   
   </td>     
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>09</td>   
   <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
   <td>Javascript Developer</td>
   <td>2009/09/15</td>
   <td>
    <div class="ui buttons">
     <button class="ui green button">Edit</button>
     <div class="or"></div>
     <button class="ui orange button">Delete</button>
    </div>   
   </td>     
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>10</td>   
   <td>Sonya Frost</td>
   <td>Software Engineer</td>
   <td>2008/12/13</td>
   <td>
    <div class="ui buttons">
     <button class="ui green button">Edit</button>
     <div class="or"></div>
     <button class="ui orange button">Delete</button>
    </div>   
   </td>     
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>11</td>   
   <td>Jena Gaines</td>
   <td>Office Manager</td>
   <td>2008/12/19</td>
   <td>
    <div class="ui buttons">
     <button class="ui green button">Edit</button>
     <div class="or"></div>
     <button class="ui orange button">Delete</button>
    </div>   
   </td>     
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>12</td>   
   <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
   <td>Support Lead</td>
   <td>2013/03/03</td>
   <td>
    <div class="ui buttons">
     <button class="ui green button">Edit</button>
     <div class="or"></div>
     <button class="ui orange button">Delete</button>
    </div>   
   </td>     
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>13</td>   
   <td>Charde Marshall</td>
   <td>Regional Director</td>
   <td>2008/10/16</td>
   <td>
    <div class="ui buttons">
     <button class="ui green button">Edit</button>
     <div class="or"></div>
     <button class="ui orange button">Delete</button>
    </div>   
   </td>     
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>14</td>   
   <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
   <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
   <td>2012/12/18</td>
   <td>
    <div class="ui buttons">
     <button class="ui green button">Edit</button>
     <div class="or"></div>
     <button class="ui orange button">Delete</button>
    </div>   
   </td>     
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>15</td>   
   <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
   <td>Regional Director</td>
   <td>2010/03/17</td>
   <td>
    <div class="ui buttons">
     <button class="ui green button">Edit</button>
     <div class="or"></div>
     <button class="ui orange button">Delete</button>
    </div>   
   </td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>16</td>   
   <td>Michael Silva</td>
   <td>Marketing Designer</td>
   <td>2012/11/27</td>
   <td>
    <div class="ui buttons">
     <button class="ui green button">Edit</button>
     <div class="or"></div>
     <button class="ui orange button">Delete</button>
    </div>   
   </td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>17</td>   
   <td>Paul Byrd</td>
   <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
   <td>2010/06/09</td>
   <td>
    <div class="ui buttons">
     <button class="ui green button">Edit</button>
     <div class="or"></div>
     <button class="ui orange button">Delete</button>
    </div>   
   </td>   
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>18</td>   
   <td>Gloria Little</td>
   <td>Systems Administrator</td>
   <td>2009/04/10</td>
   <td>
    <div class="ui buttons">
     <button class="ui green button">Edit</button>
     <div class="or"></div>
     <button class="ui orange button">Delete</button>
    </div>   
   </td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>19</td>   
   <td>Bradley Greer</td>
   <td>Software Engineer</td>
   <td>2012/10/13</td>
   <td>
    <div class="ui buttons">
     <button class="ui green button">Edit</button>
     <div class="or"></div>
     <button class="ui orange button">Delete</button>
    </div>   
   </td>    
     </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>20</td>   
   <td>Dai Rios</td>
   <td>Personnel Lead</td>
   <td>2012/09/26</td>
   <td>
    <div class="ui buttons">
     <button class="ui green button">Edit</button>
     <div class="or"></div>
     <button class="ui orange button">Delete</button>
    </div>   
   </td>    
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think by declaring your breakpoints in the initialisation of the object you would be replacing the defaults. Having only one responsive breakpoint won't make any changes.

Try to add your custom breakpoint to the default options before initialisation.

```
$.fn.dataTable.Responsive.breakpoints.push({
    name: 'fablet',
    width: 650
})

$('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: true
});
```